# How do we remove the box around plots when using PyPlot in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am plotting different functions but each plot has a box around it. I insist on using the package PyPlot.

For example, in the following code, the output has a box around it.

```
using PyPlot
plot(randn(5,5),linewidth=2)
```

I just want to have the lines of the axes alone but not the other two lines of the box.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn of the box by using the `axes` command.

However, it seems that there is no option in `axes` documentation to leave out left and bottom borders - hence you will need to plot them yourself:

```
using PyPlot
PyPlot.cla()
PyPlot.axes(frame_on=false)
plot(rand(5,5),linewidth=2)
PyPlot.plot((0,0),(0,1),color="black",linewidth=1)
PyPlot.plot((0,4),(0,0),color="black",linewidth=1)
PyPlot.display_figs() #required when run in IDE such as Atom
```

EDIT:
actually you can configure custom axes that do the job:

```
using PyPlot
PyPlot.cla()
f=figure()
f.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax = f.get_axes()[1]
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(false)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(false)
ax.plot(rand(5,5),linewidth=2)
PyPlot.display_figs()
```

Comment: I think using subplt2grid will be better

Answer (score 0):

I Tried using **subplot2grid** and I found it amazing as follows

```
using PyPlot
f=subplot2grid((1,5),(0,0),colspan = 5)
f.spines["top"].set_visible(false)
f.spines["right"].set_visible(false)
f.plot(rand(5,5),linewidth=2)
xticks([0,1,2,3,4])
```

And it produces what I wanted. It is an update from the answer from @Przemyslaw.